# client.guilds coming up as 'undefined'

Tags: discord, discord.io

Okay, so I'm writing a discord bot that outputs all the usernames in a guild (server).

Here is the code I have so far.

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord client
var client = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
client.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(client.username + ' - (' + client.id + ')');
    logger.info(client.guilds);
});
client.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our client needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '.') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'members':
                var memberList = [];
                const guild = client.guilds.get("610719306678009856");
                guild.members.forEach(member => memberList.push((member.user.username)));  
                client.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: memberList, 
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

I was getting an error from `client.guilds.get` saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

I then added the `logger.info(client.guilds)` to see if it would output, and on startup it outputs `{"message":"undefined","level":"info"}`

I've been checking the documentation, and I have 0 clue why this isn't working.

Comment: You are using the package Discord.io and not Discord.js. Discord.js has a property for clients called `guilds` to get all the servers. Discord.io has that same property but under the name of `servers`. So the fix is to replace `client.guilds` with `client.servers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `guilds` under the [properties of `Client`](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Properties.html) object as stated by the docs, but there is a `servers` property under `Client`.

So you can do `client.servers.get(idOfServer)` instead.

Comment: Im a complete idiot and was using discord.js code in a discord.io bot.